# authentication gmail api C# windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, authentication, google-api, windows-phone-8.1, gmail-api

I have a problem authenticating my app using gmail api for c#. I'd appreciate if anyone could help! myCredintial and myServer are private classes defined the the server class, every time I get the 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException error in the when AuthorizeBroker is called

```
if (myServer != null)
            return;

        Uri secrets = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json");

        myCredential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None);
        String s = myCredential.UserId;
        myServer = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = myCredential,
            ApplicationName = "test",
        });
```

Comment: Did you receive any error responses or error codes?

Comment: actually it gives me a file not found exception, which is really odd since when I pass the uri of another json file next to the intended file, it gives me another error that format mismatch or something !! Any idea ???

Comment: I think I'm little to late, but best guess would be to check if the file `Copy to output directory` setting is set to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`. Can be set in file properties in solution explorer.

Comment: I forgot to update the post, but the problem was resolved by changing "Build Action" to content in the JSON file properties.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the "Build Action" properties of files copied in a solution is null, The problem is resolved by changing "Build Action" property to Content.

Comment: Thankyou... Thankyou! Please mark as correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I am not sure what the root cause is but the solution for me was to duplicate a json file that was working and point to that one instead.

We had DataModel/SampleData.json in our project which was auto-generated by visual studio when we created a hub page. I knew this file could be loaded and thus I saved it as client_secrets.json and left it in our DataModel folder.  I also noted that the property Copy to Output Directory was set to 'Do not copy' and thus I left it as such for the client_secrets.json.

As soon as I pointed to that new file it worked.  Not sure if it was an issue with how I created the first one or the fact that it was in the assets folder or that I had set it to copy always.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working, interestingly the google api package that exist  in dev site work on my PC makes me wondering if there is something wrong with the solution settings.